# How to implement paypal Recurring Payments sandbox?

Tags: php, paypal

I was trying to implement paypal Recurring just like ARB in authorize.net to charge monthly billing to the user what I found is [this](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails) and I also found the source code [here](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/nvp_CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_php.txt).

But I am unable to find my my_api_username, my_api_password, my_api_signature as they were required in the api

```
$API_UserName = urlencode('my_api_username');
$API_Password = urlencode('my_api_password');
$API_Signature = urlencode('my_api_signature');
```

And I am unable to find them in my account in profile tab, if you have any code sample and anyone can guide me where can I find these variables in my account. I want to implement this for sandbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a post which shows you where you can find that information:
http://www.putler.com/support/faq/how-to-get-paypal-api-username-password-and-signature-information/

Comment: Thanks peacemarker I saw on that post you linked that I will need a premier or link account to get username/pass and signature